# Inverse element of "-"

Tags: arithmetic, real-numbers

What is meant by the inverse element of "-"?

There is a statement in my book that says there exists an inverse element of "-" in $\mathbb{R}$ and I have to mark it true or false. I know that the inverse element of a natural number let us say $n$ is $-n$ with respect to addition, but I don't understand what is meant by the inverse element of "-".

Comment: My answer would be that "-" is not an element of $\mathbb{R}$ and so has no inverse element in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: It's probably a typo.

Comment: Perhaps it may be suggesting that the additive inverse of $x$ is $-x$. Or perhaps not.

Comment: Maybe it means "what is the inverse *operation* of the unary minus operation (additive negation).

Comment: In which book did you see this statement? Please include an excerpt which includes the statement you are referring to.